# How to render different url based on checkbox in Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to change the view of one page depending on which checkbox is checked.
Also when one is checked another becomes unchecked.

```
<input class="searchType" type="checkbox"></input>
<input class="searchType2" type="checkbox"></input>
```

I tried something like this but I don't know how to add another solution(if another checkbox is checked)

```
$('.searchType').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));  //-->this will alert id of checked checkbox.
       if(this.checked){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'projects/index',
                data: $(this).attr('id'),

                success: function(data) {
                    alert('it worked');
                    alert(data);
                    $('#container').html(data);
                },
                 error: function() {
                    alert('it broke');
                },
                complete: function() {
                    alert('it completed');
                }
            });

            }
      });
      $('.searchType2').click(function() {
          alert($(this).attr('id'));  //-->this will alert id of checked checkbox.
          if(this.checked){
              $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: 'projects/categories',
                  data: $(this).attr('id'), 

                  success: function(data) {
                      alert('it worked');
                      alert(data);
                      $('#container').html(data);
                  },
                  error: function() {
                      alert('it broke');
                  },
                  complete: function() {
                      alert('it completed');
                  }
              });

          }
      });
```

When I try code like this, in the server console I get for first checkbox:

```
Rendering projects/index.html.erb
Completed 200 OK in 217ms (Views: 197.8ms | ActiveRecord: 7.0ms)
```

And if other is checked

```
Rendering projects/categories.html.erb
Completed 200 OK in 217ms (Views: 197.8ms | ActiveRecord: 7.0ms)
```

It seems like it works but in reality, it does not change any route, all remains the same

Cheers

Comment: If your logic flow is hitting the `error` handler it means there was a problem on the server side. As such you need to debug the code that's run in your `projects/index` endpoint, not the JS.

Comment: This means your request is failing. Check the response for server side errors

Comment: First, verify your request URL, are you accessing correct URL or not? you can use tools like a [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to troubleshoot server response and correct request format

Comment: "*when one is checked another becomes unchecked*" - use `<input type='radio'` not two checkboxes for this UX

Comment: oh, it was a typo in the index method, now the request is success. But still, don't know how to change page based on which checkbox is checked. Can you please review updated question

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-to-check-whether-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Your input has no `id` attributes, please add the `attributes`

HTML

```
<input id="1" value="1" type="checkbox" class="searchType">
<input id="2" value="2" type="checkbox" class="searchType">
```

Javacript

```
$('.searchType').click(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    var val = input.val();
       if(input.is(':checked')){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'projects/index',
                data: {id : val},

                success: function(data) {
                    alert('it worked');
                    alert(data);
                    $('#container').html(data);
                },
                 error: function() {
                    alert('it broke');
                },
                complete: function() {
                    alert('it completed');
                }
            });

            }
      });
```

Comment: Where do you get that they are not checkboxes, I'm seeing that they are checkboxes and the developer also added `if(this.checked){` to imply that they are either checkboxes or radio buttons. What else can be `checked`?

I have removed the extra attribute I added by mistake

Comment: I think by the time I commented, they were not checkboxes and there was something referring to `id`

Answer (score 0):

Since your route isn't working, you need to update the url, not the parameters.

So go the end result should be `projects/index/searchType` and not `projects/index?searchType`

The below snippet is an example that should cover all your questions.

It will uncheck any checkboxes that is not the checkbox doing the action. Though I would recommend using `select` or `radio` in this instance.

```js
var searchType = document.getElementById("searchType"); //Get the checkbox element
var searchType2 = document.getElementById("searchType2");

searchType.addEventListener("change", search); //set the onchange event for each checkbox
searchType2.addEventListener("change", search);

function search() {
    var checkbox = this;

    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=\"checkbox\"]");

    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        var chk = checkboxes[i];

        if (chk !== checkbox) {
            chk.checked = false;
        }
    }

    if (checkbox.checked) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'projects/index/' + checkbox.id,
            success: function (data) {
                alert('it worked');
                console.log(data);
                $('#container').html(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('it broke');
            },
            complete: function () {
                console.log('it completed');
            }
        });
        return;
    }

    console.log("no checkbox selected");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="searchType" class="searchType" type="checkbox"></input>
<input id="searchType2" class="searchType2" type="checkbox"></input>
```